# render Account page element based on Account team or User record field

Tags: apex, visualforce, rendered

Trying to return true for renderELEMENT based on the user being either on the AccountTeam OR having a field checked on their user record. 
Able to produce based on just either part, but Not able to get the either / or quality working. thanks for help!

```
 public class AccountTeamChecker {
    private ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public AccountTeamChecker(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }
    // Returns true if the user is an account team member
    public Boolean renderELEMENT{
        get {
            if (renderELEMENT== null) {
                renderELEMENT= [
                        select count()
                        from AccountTeamMember
                        where AccountId = :sc.getId()
                        and UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
                   //   and AccountAccessLevel in ('Read', 'Edit', 'All')
                        ] > 0;


            } else {
                        renderELEMENT= [
                    select Admin_Team__c
                    from User
                    where Id = :Userinfo.getUserId()
                    ].Admin_Team__c;

            system.debug('====================='+renderELEMENT);
            }

            return renderELEMENT;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking them one after another like this is probably the cleanest way to do it:

```
public Boolean renderELEMENT{
    get {
        if (renderELEMENT == null) {
            renderELEMENT = checkUser();
        }
        return renderELEMENT;
    }
    private set;
}

private Boolean checkUser() {
    if ([select count() from User
            where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() and Admin_Team__c = true] > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if ([select count() from AccountTeamMember
            and UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() and AccountId = :sc.getId()] > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```